# No error in code but Login is not working for python selenium simple script

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
username ="//input[@placeholder='Username']"
password ="//input[@placeholder='Password']"

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, username).send_keys("Admin")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, password).send_keys("admin123")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Login']").click()
print("Test pass")
```

Above script is not having driver.close() but still chrome is getting closed automatically and login page is not opening

Not sure what mistake I am doing here

I am expecting Logged in paged after given login credentials
But chrome is getting closed instead

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code and try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(<chromedriver.exe path>), options=options)

driver.get(<URL>)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
so you can follow the code , it will correctly execute..
        
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
        
        
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        
username ="//input[@placeholder='Username']"
password ="//input[@placeholder='Password']"
        
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,username).send_keys("Admin")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,password).send_keys("admin123")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[normalizespace()='Login']").click()
        
act_title = driver.title
exp_title ="OrangeHRM"
        
if act_title==exp_title:
  print("pass")
else:
   print("fail")
```